# Ported from cocos2d on cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to port the game written in cocos2d on cocos2d-x? Without rewriting the code yourself with objective-c on c++? Thanks)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocos2d-x support only C++, JavaScript and Lua for cross-platform development. Therefore you must have to rewrite entire code.